# Maximizing revenue for ticket price

Tags: maxima-minima

A rail company, QNRail, is selling tickets for a special trip from Toronto to Winnipeg.
The train’s maximum capacity is 200 passengers. All tickets are sold at the same price p in Canadian
dollars. Based on market research, they know that the quantity q of tickets demanded depends on
the price p charged per ticket, according to the formula below.

q = (300 − 2p if p < 100

250 −
3/2
p if p ≥ 100)

In order to maximize their revenue for this trip, how much should QNRail charge per ticket? Please
show all of your reasoning! Round your final answer to the nearest cent.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I speak about the first equation, the principle is the same for the second one.

$300 − 2p$ represents the number of tickets sold at a certain price.

So $(300 − 2p) * p$ represents the revenue.

From the derivative $300 - 4p$ you can see the maximum at $p = 75$

Putting this value in the function $(300 − 2p) * p$ you find the maximum revenue for a price $p < 100$

Do the same for the other case and compare the results.